# Unable to restart the queue manager

Tags: ibm-mq

Unable to restart the queue manager getting error message as AMQ7017 Log not available
Checked the FDC file and getting the error message as  AMQ6118 An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred 7017
We have remounted the file system and log file is also exists but still not able to restart the queue manager
please let us know your suggestions ASAP

Comment: What MQ version is this happening on? Is the log writeable, is the file system mounted with both read and write allowed? Is there nothing further in the FDC?

Answer (score 0):

The queue manager generates AMQ7017 for different reasons and following are some of the reasons.

1. The queue manager was not able to find a specific log file

   - Your update indicates the log file is there.
2. Problem in accessing the log file

   - Check the file permissions of the log files and log control file
3. If you see any FDCs with BADLSN errors, then there is a possibility of
   a MQ defect or a file system issue.

   - Check for any known defects fixed. But in some cases, an APAR fix only
     prevents the problem in future and may not fix the current issue in
     queue manager restart.

An immediate workaround would be to backup the queue manager and then rebuild or recreate the queue manager or restore from backup. If this not an option then I suggest opening ticket with IBM.